# How to keep my Materialize modal open if validation failed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, materialize

I am working with **Laravel** and **Materialize CSS**. I made a simple registration form within a modal. When I click the **Submit** button, the modal closes and errors are displayed in the next `div` on page. After I reopen it, I can see the errors on the modal. How do I keep the modal open if the validation fails?

Comment: are you using jquery?

Comment: I don't know how jQ or MCSS does it but just look for their JS methods. Just put the `.close()` before the `else`. You say if `IsSignedIn`, for example, _then_ `close`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to laravel's `$errors` variable, you can check if the validation passed or failed. 
You can use an `if/else` to check if it failed and add a script to open the modal

```
@if($errors->any())
<script>
$('#myModal').modal('show'); 
</script>
@endif
```

NB: This requires the use of `jquery`

Comment: Hi thanks for helping I tried this it doesn't work Uncaught Error: Method show does not exist on jQuery.modal . I tried with 'open' and I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined . I tried the code in all blades and made sure all other js loads first still nothing.I am a beginer maybe I missed something . I will keep at it

Comment: Did you replace the #mymodal with your modal id?

Comment: Yes I did  .modal('open') works in my js file but that pops it open on load

Comment: You mean the modal pops open on load...  with or without errors?

Comment: If I use $('#modal1').modal('open'); instead of just $('#modal1').modal(); in my Js file it opens the modal on window load and its there until I close it . But it doesn't close  when validation is wrong like before. a good sign :) maybe I will find something around this.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I got it thanks for help!

```
@if($errors->any())
   <script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#myModal').modal('open');
    });

   </script>
@endif
```